# Android Java logging location and telephony data to binary file every second

Tags: java, android, serialization, timer

Does anyone know how to design architecture (logic) behind to log object states (or primitive data types) and to store the data in binary file. File will be send to server instance and parse there.

So, if I'm correct I need to use:

- Timer class (and other helper classes) for time based logging (periodically - every specific amount of ms or s).
- Java Serializable for object/primitive types serialization for binary file. (can file serialize in java could be deserialize in .net?)
- Two phase REST service for submitting file to server

Do you suggest another approach? How to design this approach above and not violate OOP paradigms?

BR,
JDK

Comment: I found that google protocol buffers will be better choice than java serialization. Does android support google proto buffers